# What test to use to show that methods are different / not equal

Tags: r, normal-distribution, nonparametric, differences

so I have this graph
[image: graph]
What test can I use to show that the three methods are different / not equal? The data is not normally distributed, nor has it a common variance. I also failed to transform it to a normal distribution.
I'm working in R if that helps.
The sample size is 1000, maybe that solves all problems of non-normality and I can simply use an ANOVA?

Comment: Huh??? Looking at that graph how could you possibly believe the methods were _not_ different. Looks like a case for the "Inter Ocular Trauma Test" https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/31/the-iot-test/

Comment: You could fit two GAMs, one stratified by method, one not, and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea, you could ignore the models and timesteps and just compare the values, with anova or kruskal-wallis. This isn't very elegant, but with data that clearly separated, it gives you the magic p-value.

Another idea, if you can put 95% confidence intervals around the models on the plot, the fact that the intervals don't overlap would suggest that the methods are different.  Again, nothing fancy, but it does the job.

Comment: thanks. i'll plot them with confidence intervals then. looks nice too :)
its really obvious that they are not the same anyways.